# How to tell OCaml compiler the path of recently installed module

Tags: csv, ocaml

I already have OCaml installed on my Mac by running these commands:

```
$ brew install opam
$ opam init --bare -a -y
$ opam switch create cs3110-2022fa ocaml-base-compiler.4.14.0
```

Running any OCaml code which only uses Standard library modules works fine. Then I want to do a few things that are not covered with it, e.g [reading CSV files](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/csv/).

```
$ opam install csv
```

Let's try to compile [this code](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv/blob/master/examples/example.ml)

```
open Printf
open Csv

let embedded_csv = "\
\"Banner clickins\"
\"Clickin\",\"Number\",\"Percentage\",
\"brand.adwords\",\"4,878\",\"14.4\"
\"vacation.advert2.adwords\",\"4,454\",\"13.1\"
\"affiliates.generic.tc1\",\"1,608\",\"4.7\"
\"brand.overture\",\"1,576\",\"4.6\"
\"vacation.cheap.adwords\",\"1,515\",\"4.5\"
\"affiliates.generic.vacation.biggestchoice\",\"1,072\",\"3.2\"
\"breaks.no-destination.adwords\",\"1,015\",\"3.0\"
\"fly.no-destination.flightshome.adwords\",\"833\",\"2.5\"
\"exchange.adwords\",\"728\",\"2.1\"
\"holidays.cyprus.cheap\",\"574\",\"1.7\"
\"travel.adwords\",\"416\",\"1.2\"
\"affiliates.vacation.generic.onlinediscount.200\",\"406\",\"1.2\"
\"promo.home.topX.ACE.189\",\"373\",\"1.1\"
\"homepage.hp_tx1b_20050126\",\"369\",\"1.1\"
\"travel.agents.adwords\",\"358\",\"1.1\"
\"promo.home.topX.SSH.366\",\"310\",\"0.9\""


let csvs =
  List.map (fun name -> name, Csv.load name)
           [ "examples/example1.csv"; "examples/example2.csv" ]


let () =
  let ecsv = Csv.input_all(Csv.of_string embedded_csv) in
    printf "---Embedded CSV---------------------------------\n" ;
    Csv.print_readable ecsv;

  List.iter (
    fun (name, csv) ->
      printf "---%s----------------------------------------\n" name;
      Csv.print_readable csv
  ) csvs;
  printf "Compare (Embedded CSV) example1.csv = %i\n"
         (Csv.compare ecsv (snd(List.hd csvs)))

let () =
  (* Save it to a file *)
  let ecsv = Csv.input_all(Csv.of_string embedded_csv) in
  let fname = Filename.concat (Filename.get_temp_dir_name()) "example.csv" in
  Csv.save fname ecsv;
  printf "Saved CSV to file %S.\n" fname
```

The result is:

```
$ ocamlopt csvdemo.ml -o csvdemo         
File "csvdemo.ml", line 2, characters 5-8:
2 | open Csv
         ^^^
Error: Unbound module Csv
```

How to tell OCaml compiler where to find Csv module path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a wonderful place to use Dune, but going a little bit old school you can use ocamlfind to locate the package.

```
% cat test2.ml
open Csv

let () = print_endline "hello"
% ocamlopt -I `ocamlfind query csv` -o test2 csv.cmxa test2.ml
% ./test2
hello
%
```

Or alternatively:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package csv -o test2 cvs.cmxa test2.ml
```

Comment: `ocamlopt -I `ocamlfind query csv` test2.ml -o test2` gives "Error: No implementations provided for the following modules: Csv referenced from csvdemo.cmx". The output of `ocamlfind query csv` is "
/Users/andre/.opam/cs3110-2022fa/lib/csv". Hmm OCaml tooling is a bit confusing

Comment: What happens if you try the second form?

Comment: Same error message like the previous command. Dune works. I think it's a bit "cumbersome" though to compile a single short file using build system

Comment: Edited to link in the csv implementation.

Comment: This should work now. Please let me know if there are still any faults.

Comment: That works. I guess if my code depends on more libraries, like foo and bar, then I do this: `ocamlopt -I `ocamlfind query foo bar` -o test2 foo.cmxa bar.cmxa test2.ml`?

Comment: Try running that command and see what it gives you. Would that be useful, or would you be better off with ``ocamlopt -I `ocamlfind query foo` -I `ocamlfind query bar`  baz.ml``?